# what if I run a ubuntu base image on a host with an older kernel?

Tags: docker

if I build a ubuntu(like 16.04) base image,then I build a container by this image in a Centos host.will host kernel do some effect on container?

Comment: The container is an isolated environment from the host. So it will not do some effect on the container.

Comment: It depends on the kernel version. Dockers can share some kernel calls, so, you cannot deploy correctly a docker with a kernel much newer than kernel version in the host. Otherwise, older is possible without effect in the container, independently that if it's CentOS, ubuntu, or other linux.

Answer (score 1):

Docker containers share the host’s kernel when they’re run.  `docker build` internally launches a series of containers, so if one of your Dockerfile steps does something that’s kernel-dependent you could in theory get different results if the image was built on different systems.  In turn, regardless of where the image was built, when you run it, it will use the current host’s kernel.

In practice, programs that have deep kernel-level dependencies (for example, depend on specific modules being loaded) are hard to run under Docker; you wind up needing to break a lot of the isolation Docker offers to run the program at all, and it’s usually easier and better to run these sorts of programs on the host.

The flip side of this is that “routine” server-type Docker images (for example, the sorts of Python, Node, and PHP applications that are ubiquitous on SO) aren’t that sensitive to the kernel at all, and so long as your kernel is new enough to successfully run Docker it doesn’t really matter.